# setLocation redirect to page?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

I think that my problem is with my servlet. When I edit web.xml file and I do mapping /MyProject/* does work but my UI not.

example

```
<!-- Here my UI works -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Here my ValidateEmail.html in WebContent work, but my UI not -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyProject/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I use mapping /MyProject/* the url: localhost:8080/MyProject/ValidateEmail.html works but the localhost:8080/MyProject doesn't.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you checked that you can open the page without redirecting?

Comment: I moved the EmailActivated.html file to WebContent folder. I tried use open() and setLocation() but does not work also !

Comment: Have you tried to open the page by entering the url to the browser? E.g. http://localhost:8080/myapp/EmailActivated.html

Comment: yep, I tried but does not display !

Comment: Well, then you are asking a wrong question.

Comment: wrong question ? why ? I should ask where I add my html file to be displayed ?